# Android gradient not divisible by 45

Tags: android-drawable, linear-gradients

I am trying set angle in gradient 60 degrees. Eclipse and android generate the error:

```
06-23 13:29:06.317: E/AndroidRuntime(8013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 13:29:06.317: E/AndroidRuntime(8013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                      activity ComponentInfo{com.web.qooface/com.web.qooface.ui.activities.CompetitionActivity}:    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class   android.widget.TableLayout
06-23 13:29:06.317: E/AndroidRuntime(8013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
```

When I set 45 or 90 - no problem.
Here is the xml:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="135.0"
    android:startColor="@color/competion_table_background_start_gradient"
    android:endColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

`android:angle`

Integer. The angle for the gradient, in degrees. 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top. 
**It must be a multiple of 45. Default is 0.**

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. Thanks. Paid no attention.  But how return on other degree?

Comment: not possible at the moment, just multiples of 45 degrees…